# Directional Derivatives vs Gradient [Assignment Question, Read Description]

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I know we are not supposed to ask assignment questions but I would be grateful if someone would help. This is my first question so please forgive any mistakes. I also don't know how to write math formulas on a computer properly so please bear with me.

The question is basically:

> $f(x,y,z) = y^2 +  + ^2^3$

We are told that the directional derivative at $P(1,2,-1)$ is maximum along a direction $||$ to $z$ axis and the maximum value is $64$.

I used the formula for directional derivative parallel to a unit vector $u = <u_x,u_y,u_z>$ is found as $$D_uf(P_0) = lim_{s\to0} \frac{ [f(x_0+s(a_x),y_0+s(u_y),z_0+s(u_z))-f(P_0)]}{s}. $$

I used that here to calculate $df/ds = \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{[c(-1+s)^2-c(-1)^2]}{s} = 64$ finally giving $c = -32$. Then I found $a$, $b$ by equating the $x$ and $y$ components of the gradient del f to 0.

In this particular case, we use $$ u = <0,0,1> $$

But, my problem is that when I use $\Delta f \cdot u$, it does not give 64.(Dot product of gradient of f and the vector u)

Can someone tell where I went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @RadPrad check how to write maths so as people here can understand the formulation in first place.

Comment: @HungerLearn Is it more readeable now? Someone helped edit it.

Comment: @RadPRad Kind of yes...

Comment: @HungerLearn I don't know how to write grad f properly. Hope you were able to understand.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to compute the gradient of $f$.

You will find
$$
f_x = ay^2+3cx^2z^2, f_y=2axy+bz, f_z=by+2cx^3z
$$
When evaluated at point (1,2,-1), it takes the form
$$
f_x = 4a+3c, f_y=4a-b, f_z=2b-2c
$$
The other information is that at this point, the gradient writes
$$
f_x=0, f_y=0, f_z=64
$$
By solving the 3-by-3 linear system, you will find the desired coefficients.

Comment: Thank you. What is the mistake in my method?